# How do I keep part of the page static in jquery mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile

I want to develop a single page app using jquery mobile, and want to have a menu on the side (similar to the facebook app for iphone). This side menu needs to stay static on the page, and only the main content of the page change when the links are clicked.

i.e. I want to have a `<div>` outside of the `data-role="page"` that still has jquery mobile controls in it, but doesn't change with the page content.

If I try doing just that, I cannot find any way to apply the jquery mobile styling to the controls in the side menu.

I have put together my example here: http://jsfiddle.net/ka6pz/5/

Comment: The FB app for the iPhone isn't shown all the time, only on swipe; not sure if that's what you want or not. If you always want the menu to be showing all the time, you could create a jQM navbar and restructure the CSS's width/heights plus set a max-width for the page so it doesn't conflict with the bar. If you want something like the FB app, you could create a separate page and on 'swiperight', have the new page slide out.

Comment: The hiding/showing can be done really easily with CSS animation, that bit is not so much my problem and I left it out to simplify the problem. I did try something based on a Navbar, but nothing outside the div with `data-role="page"` actually picks up any of the jquery mobile styling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Someone answered this on another forum: https://forum.jquery.com/topic/jquery-mobile-elements-outside-page